# Can webhooks be delivered straight to Azure Event Hubs?

Tags: azure, webhooks, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

I've read a lot of documentation on Azure about working with Shared Access Signatures, and I don't believe it's possible to have webhooks delivered straight to Evenhtubs.  I believe an intermediate service like a an Azure Function or Logic App currently needs to act as a middleman.

Is it correct to say that the service generating the webhook would have to choose to implement the signing scheme used by Azure Shared Access Signatures for Eventhubs to receive such a webhook?

Furthermore, is there any Azure PAAS service such as document DB or Azure SQL which has an API authentication scheme which a fairly simple webhook could write directly to?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do event hub programming? If it is that case, please refer to  [Get start with eventhub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-java-ephjava-getstarted).

Comment: No, I want to know if Eventhubs authentication mechanism is compatible with authentication mechanisms found in most services that are capable of sending webhooks.

Answer (score 9):

It's been awhile since this question was asked but I'll put the answer here for anyone who needs it.

Yes,  you can have a webhook send directly to an Event Hub. The client needs to send a post request with the Shared Access Signature (SAS) in the Authorization header and data in the body.

Here is Microsoft's documentation on the process. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event